# In terror, his body ... "curled up" or "squirmed" or "coiled" or ...?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, differences

I am describing somebody who in his memory re-experiences a terrible event (say, an air raid), and his body bends / gets twisted. Would one say his body is...

- curled up?
- coiled?
- squirmed?
- [something else]?

> In terror, his body ______

What would be the subtle differences between these three words (or more suggestions)?

Answer (score 2):

You could also consider:

[contort](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contorted): to twist in a violent manner 
[writhe](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/writhe): 1. to twist into coils or folds OR 2. to twist (the body or a bodily part) in pain.

While not a single word, *the fetal position* is used for someone curled into something like a ball and is often related to a serious stress reaction.

While not specifically relating to curling, other words to evoke a negative reaction could include *cringe*, *tremble*, *recoil*, or *convulse*.

Answer (score 1):

"Writhed" or "Squirmed" are probably your best bets because they imply struggle, pain, and disgust.